# How to make sure that first random value is always bigger than the second?

Tags: python

Code:

```
def Division():

    print "************************\n""********DIVISION********\n""************************"
    counter = 0
    import random
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    y = random.randint(1,10)
    answer = x/y
    print "What will be the result of " + str(x) + '/' + str(y) + " ?"
    print "\n"
    userAnswer = input ("Enter result: ")
    if userAnswer == answer:
        print ("Well done!")
        print "\n"
        userInput = raw_input ("Do you want to continue? \n Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.")
        if userInput == "y":
            print "\n"
            Division()
        else:
            print "\n"
            Menu()
    else:
        while userAnswer != answer:
            counter += 1
            print "Try again"
            userAnswer = input ("Enter result: ")
            if counter == 3: break
        userInput = raw_input ("Do you want to continue? \n Enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no.")
        if userInput == "y":
            print "\n"
            Division()
        else:
            print "\n"
            Menu()
```

In this case I want `x` value to be always bigger than `y` value. How to do I do it?
Code for subtraction is similar and the question remains the same, target is to avoid
negative result.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question, but for your future questions, think about not giving a wall of code to read through when you have a small and specific problem. This easily could have been "Given two numbers, how do you make x = small one and y = big one?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if `x < y` and swap them e.g.

```
if x < y:
    x, y = y, x
```

Note in python you can swap two variables without need of a temporary variable.

You can even take further shortcut by using bultin `min` and `max` and do it in a single line e.g.

```
x, y = max(x,y), min(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anurag Uniyal, I'm still learning there for I'm really happy that there are people like yourself who are ready to help out those who seek for answers.

Comment: @Geostigmata you are welcome, you can select it as answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Anrag Uniyal's answer, you might also try this:

```
y,x = sorted([x,y])
```

Comment: Got my program finished! Thank you guys - never thought that the response would be so quick ! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do randint between x and 10 to get a number greater than x:

```
x = random.randint(1,10)
y = random.randint(x,10)
```

Comment: It may not matter, but be aware that this subtly changes the distribution of the values. Take x=2, y=3 as an example. In the original, this combination would occur with probability 2(0.1 * 0.1) = 0.02 (x=2 and y=3 or x=3 and y=2 after swapping). Using this approach, it would occur with probability 0.1 * (0.125) = 0.0125 (x=2, then y=3 from 3..10)